# Issues in getting internet from another node through Ethernet

Tags: centos, internet, forwarding

I am trying to get internet on **node1** [IP: 1.2.3.4] from another **node2** [IP: 5.6.7.8] which has a working internet connection, through ethernet.

Packet forwarding is enabled on the `node2` which is connected to internet:

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
```

I am able to ssh from each node to the other.

The `ip route` command on **node1** shows

```
default via 5.6.7.8 dev enp4s0f0
default via 5.6.7.8 dev enp4s0f0 proto static metric 100
```

In the `resolv.conf` on **node1**, I have set the nameserver as `5.6.7.8`.

When I try to do `ping google.com` on **node1**, I get a message:

```
ping: google.com: Name or service not known
```

Can someone please help me figure out this issue.

Thanks

Comment: did you try the solution from here? https://serverfault.com/questions/306024/how-to-route-network-traffic-of-a-host-via-another-host

Comment: I did try that method but it doesn't work.

Comment: What was done about NAT?

Comment: It seems I am able to ping google.com (172.217.15.78), but DNS is not setup properly so I get error when trying to ping google.com.

Answer (score 0):

The link provided by Bart in the comments helped me to solve the issue: https://serverfault.com/questions/306024/how-to-route-network-traffic-of-a-host-via-another-host

I had to set up the NAT and add default route to make it work. Thanks for the help guys.